# Multiple Inheritance in nhibernate with joined subclass

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have two Base classes **Student** and **Course** and one subclass **StudentCourse** which inherit properties of these two base classes.

Is it possible to do such inheritance with Joined subclass?

I have tried by creating interfaces for both **Student** and **Course** class as below:

```
public interface StudentInterface
    {
        Int32 StudentId { get; set; }

    }

 public interface InterfaceCourse
    {

        Int32 CourseId { get; set; }

    }
```

**Code for student.cs**

it implements StudentInterface

```
public class Student:StudentInterface 
    {
        [Key]
        public virtual Int32 **StudentId** { get; set; }
        public virtual string StudentName { get; set; }
        public virtual  DateTime Dob { get; set; }
        public virtual string Gender { get; set; }
        public virtual string Email { get; set; }
}
```

**code for course.cs**

```
public class Course:InterfaceStudentCourse
    {
        [Key]
        public virtual Int32 **CourseId** { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

**Code for studentCourse.cs**
it implements both base classes Student and Course
Here i want to make StudentCourse own primary key,not of it should be of superclass primary key.They should be foreign here as shown in StudentCourse.cs below

```
public class StudentCourse:StudentInterface,InterfaceCourse
    {
        [Key]
        public virtual Int32 **StudentCourseId** { get; set; }
        public override Int32  StudentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Int32 CourseId { get; set; }
   }
```

Mapping files are:

**StudentInterface.hbm.xml**

```
<class name ="StudentInterface" table="StudentInterface" >
    <id name="StudentId" type="Int32" column="StudentId" >
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>

    <joined-subclass name="Student">
      <key column="StudentId"/>
      <property name="StudentName"/>
      <property name="Dob"/>
      <property name="Gender"/>
      <property name="Email"/>
*// Need this subclass in both Student and course.....but giving duplication entity error*
      **<joined-subclass name="StudentCourse">
        <key column="StudentCourseId"/>
        <property name="StudentId"/>
        <property name="CourseId"/>
     </joined-subclass>**

    </joined-subclass>

  </class>
```

CourseInterface.hbm.xml

```
<class name ="InterfaceCourse" table="InterfaceCourse" >
    <id name="CourseId" type="Int32" column="CourseId" >
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>


    <joined-subclass name ="Course" >
      <key column="CourseId"/>
      <property name="Name"/>
   *// Need this subclass in both Student and course.....but giving duplication entity error*
**<joined-subclass name="StudentCourse">
            <key column="StudentCourseId"/>
            <property name="StudentId"/>
            <property name="CourseId"/>
         </joined-subclass>**
    </joined-subclass>
  </class>
```

*So the problem is when i made  the StudentCourse joined subclass in only one base class,then it gives error like :*

**{"Could not find a getter for property 'StudentName' in class 'Core.Model.StudentCourse'"}**

*and when i made StudentCourse joined subclass in both base classes (student,course),then error like:*

**{"Duplicate class/entity mapping Core.Model.StudentCourse"}**

*I know creating same subclass by joined subclass is not possible....
Will anyone plz tell me wat should i do to make multiple inheritance possible in such scenario.....*

**Thanks in advance...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the first i will clear you that it is not possible to do Multiple inheritance by joined-subclass or subclass in NH.

another think at the point of joined-subclass the example you are taking is wrong (i think so)

in joined subclass u must have an parent class like animal and you can inherit this to cat,dog etc..by using joined-subclass...

about your example it is best to use normal mapping like--

**take studID and CourseID in Student_Course as composite** or take an PK for Student_Course and StudID and CustomerID

but as per my exp it is best practice to make composite with one-to-many relationship..

hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Steav....u cleared my doubt....now i have taken StudentCourseId as Pk and Studentid and courseId as FK...it worked....